System Particle "Bug"
I have a problem with the particle system that I can't solve.
How can I make it so that it doesn't make that weird cut in the particles when it turns around? I've been trying to do it for a while and I can't.
https://streamable.com/k2jbuc


You have irregular shaped particle objects, and they're "spawning" in  at the beginning of the curve. If every frame another dice spawns in but its a completely different size than the previous it will "pop". That or you have an incomplete "spin" animation for each individual dice, which means they're rotating from 0 to less than 360 and then snapping back to 0 in one frame.

Those are just gueses tho, Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing. It will be easier to figure out if we can take a look ourselves.

Let me know if you found any bug or any solution @Jakemoyo

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

All good @DuarteFarrajotaRamos but do you know how do you can help me w/my ´problem?

Please share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there rather than putting it on an external site where it won't remain available to future users of this site reading your question.

@JohnEason I tried but the page doesn´t respond.

Works fine here! - Just tried it.

@JohnEason I recently uploaded the .blend! hope you can help me

@Jakemoyo  I recently uploaded the .blend! hope you can help me

Not really my field of expertise I'm afraid. The file has downloaded fine thanks so others here may be able to help.

I think the whole setup would be much easier if you just did it with GeoNodes. Its a pretty simple setup. Just instance your dice onto a BezierCircle and animate the BezierCircle's rotation to get the spin.




Thanks man! I really appreciate you ❤️ I´ll start to learn geometry nodes

Cool if this works for you can you accept the answer so it gets removed from the unanswered questions queue?
